# SegmentControll problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

A new bie here...

I am using a segmentController..in that there are three segments...Say segment A,B,C

Now I want this functionality...

when I press Segment A..Table A comes up..
when I press Segment B..Table B comes up..and
when I press Segment c..Table C comes up

well I know all the label change and that stuff...but what about the tables?? and again when I press the row elements they navigates me to another views and I want segment control to be displayed in navigated view also..

well ... can anyone please tell me how to do this??

any suggestion..any tutorial..any example code...any logic...anything....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/) is the link shows the simple Segment control. And when you want to add a Table , it is having the sample process , connect the delegates and data source. [HERE](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13493-segment-control-troubles.html) is the descussion on the kind of similar question as your one.

This is the [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) of Segment control, which provides you a lot many examples this shall help you.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks buddy..i'll surly try this out and let you know